# PHP - Looping through and adding/appending items to an array

Tags: php, arrays

Newbie coder here. I am attempting to modify some code that I have that basically looks through a database and returns in an array dates that are booked for vacation rental for the said property. However, in a long story short, I need to compare TWO properties and create and array of BOTH of the days booked in one array.  So basically, I need one long array from two sets of queries.

I think I have the CONCEPT, just not the exact syntax needed because it seems my array is being overwritten on the second, third, fourth, whatever loop.

```
$bookedDates = array();
$idlist = explode(',', $_GET['id']);   //stored as integers, ie 342,653

foreach ($idlist as $ids) {
    $sql = "exec dbo.SProc_OnlineBookedDays '" 
                . $database->escapeString($ids) . "', " 
                . date('m', $startDate) . ", " . date('Y', $startDate);

    $resultsArray = $database->query($sql);

    if ($resultsArray) {
        foreach ($resultsArray as $row) {
            $bookedDates[] = strtotime(date('m', $startDate) . '/' 
                            . $row['computed'] . '/' . date('Y', $startDate));
        }
    }
}
print_r($bookedDates);
```

I have a feeling the issue is around that bookedDates[] syntax. Yes? Thank you in advance for any help!

The array displays ONLY the last of the $ids, NOT arrays combined.

Example:
Results From Record 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'apple'
    [1] => 'cranberry'
    [2] => 'juice'
)
```

Results from Record 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'oranges'
    [1] => 'pineapple'
    [2] => 'rasberry'
)
```

They SHOULD be combined into

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'apple'
    [1] => 'cranberry'
    [2] => 'juice'
    [3] => 'oranges'
    [4] => 'pineapple'
    [5] => 'rasberry'
)
```

But I am only getting the Record 1 results during the print_r.

Comment: What result do you expect? The code you provided will get results for each `$ids` and append them to `$bookedDates`.

Comment: Try `print_r` after `foreach` loop and you'll see how your array looks and if it's empty

Comment: The result that is outputting (in this example with 2 ids) provides ONE array with the values of the later $ids when I do a print_r. I am updating the post with this info now.

Comment: well, you *are* creating one array, what do else do you expect?

Comment: Are you sure the first id returns a nonempty result?

Comment: Yep, sure am Andy. Each of my IDs when run independently return a different set of results. But combining them does not.  Yes, of course Nordenheim, lets simplify it. My first loop has values of "apple, cranberry, juice". My second loop has values of "oranges, pineapple, raspberry".  The print_r is ONLY showing me the values in my second loop, NOT the combination of "apple, cranberry, juice, oranges, pineapple, rasberry."

Answer (score 0):

well... you could use `array_merge( $arr1, $arr2 );` [[docs]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead of looping through all the elements... but if you're getting the results from just one of the arrays, it's likely that one of the queries it's returning an empty result.

on the other hand, you should avoid executing queries on a foreach loop; you might want to check if there's any way to get the results for both days using a single query.

Answer (score 0):

If your array key is the same you could use array_merge which basically merges the two arrays into one am i right in what your asking

```
$array_one = array('0' => 'oranges', '1' => 'pineapple', '2' => 'rasberry');
$array_two = array('0' => 'apple', '1' => 'cranberry', '2' => 'juice');

$outcome = array_merge($array_one, $array_two);
```

Comment: I thought about that Dava. However, and again, this could be syntax, where do I get the names of the arrays?  I could have 10 different arrays that need to be merged together. How do I set "$bookedDates[]" to be a variable of however many arrays I need? And then how to do I do an "array_merge" on an indefinite number of arrays with different names that I don't know? :)

Comment: could you provide more info as the results returned from the database because if your getting an array of dates why should you need more than once for this? from the code at the start of the topic i can see you are creating some sort of booking page i might be able to advise on a better solution for you